# Which user run webservice on this linux account?

Tags: linux

This is a follow up to my previous question. [Why wordpress cannot write to directory and how to fix it?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313913/why-wordpress-cannot-write-to-directory-and-how-to-fix-it)

I was told to run

```
apache   19314  0.0  2.2 582204 22804 ?        S    Sep14   0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                                                                                                              -DFOREGROUND
root     26805  0.0  0.0 112704   964 pts/0    S+   07:11   0:00 grep --color=au                                                                                                                                                             to -E apache|nginx
apache   31370  0.0  4.3 612032 44676 ?        S    Sep12   0:47 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                                                                                                              -DFOREGROUND
apache   31371  0.0  4.5 613940 46328 ?        S    Sep12   0:45 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                                                                                                              -DFOREGROUND
apache   31372  0.0  4.5 613988 46360 ?        S    Sep12   0:44 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                                                                                                              -DFOREGROUND
apache   31373  0.0  4.6 614716 47220 ?        S    Sep12   0:47 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                                                                                                              -DFOREGROUND
apache   31374  0.0  4.6 615044 47700 ?        S    Sep12   0:52 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                                                                                                              -DFOREGROUND
apache   31379  0.0  4.6 614544 47184 ?        S    Sep12   0:53 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                                                                                                              -DFOREGROUND
apache   31446  0.0  4.1 601428 42268 ?        S    Sep12   0:42 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                                                                                                              -DFOREGROUND
apache   31447  0.0  4.3 611672 44288 ?        S    Sep12   0:48 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                                                                                                              -DFOREGROUND
apache   31448  0.0  2.6 593976 26560 ?        S    Sep12   0:49 /usr/sbin/httpd                                                                                                                                                              -DFOREGROUND
[root@centos-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01 ~]#
```

I believe the owner of the service should be apache

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `apache` is the default user for `httpd` on CentOS.